# how to write a user script that embed the widget from clyp.it

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

I would like to record audio and share it without leaving a website.The code works on https://news.ycombinator.com/ which looks like this: http://prntscr.com/etyzgz

But it does not work on the site I want: www.zhihu.com
The button stays at the bottom of the page and the widget does not load after clicking it.

Here is the code:

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...

    /*--- Create a button in a container div.  It will be styled and
    positioned with CSS.
*/ 
var zNode       = document.createElement ('div');
zNode.setAttribute ('id', 'myContainer');
zNode.style.position = 'fixed';
zNode.style.top = 50;
zNode.style.right = 50;
zNode.innerHTML = '<button id="myButton" type="button">use clyp to send voice message</button>';
document.body.appendChild(zNode);

//--- Activate the newly added button.
document.getElementById ("myButton").addEventListener('click',function(){

    var iframe       = document.createElement ('iframe');
    iframe.src = "https://clyp.it/recording-widget";
    iframe.style.width = 400;
    iframe.style.height = 400;
    document.getElementById ("myContainer").appendChild (iframe);
});


})();
```

Comment: Try with https://clyp.it/widgets Embedded Recorder

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The widget seems great. It works well on codepen. But it is invisible when I tried to add it to an existing web page using tampermonkey. Is there anything that I neglected? I use document.createElement('iframe')  and then document.body.appendChild() to add. Sorry don't know how to add code to comment

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with that website(because I don't know Chinese). Try checking the console for any error.

Comment: It does not introduce new errors. I could find my **div** appended to the bottom of **body**. But clicking it does not show anything on the page. Inserting my **div** between the element of the source code seems to work. But the **iframe** is invisible after clicking the button. Maybe I should insert the **div** in a better place?